Quarkus Arc blocks Multi-Module Build in case of unset Properties in Module Build
I have a Quarkus Multi-Module Project (with Gradle), with following projects:

Core
Module1
Service1

Module1 contains an @ApplicationScope class that defines following Variable:
@Inject
@DataSource("database1")
AgroalDataSource dataSource;

When i now start the Gradle Build with following command (excluding tests)...
gradle clean build -x test

i get following error:
Unsatisfied dependency for type io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource and qualifiers [@Default]

The reason for the Error is, that the Module1 does not contain an application.properties file that defines the DataSource. But it also should not contain this, because the Service1 is the Quarkus Application where the application.properties should define the "Runtime-Configuration" for itself and for all Modules (Core, Module1) that it uses.
It seems Quarkus Arc already needs to be able to resolve Configurations at Build-Time, and not at Runtime, to compile them directly into the Code, which contradicts the fact that Modules are often only "Liveable" together with the Services that they are run within.

Used:

Gradle 8.6
Quarkus 3.9.5
Intellij 2024.1.1


Requirement: Unit-Tests with QuarkusTest

The Modules contain QuarkusTest Unit-Tests, because the Modules need to contain Fragments of the Service-Application (Mono-Repo with Modularity), and it is necessary to also be able to use Quarkus Arc for Dependency-Injection and Quarkus Startup-Events (among others), and to be able to use this Dependency-Injections during the Tests we can not use normal Junit5 Tests, but need to use QuarkusTest Tests.

because we need to use QuarkusTest, we want Intellij to also be able to start those tests via the UI. When starting a QuarkusTest via the UI in Intellij, following two Gradle-Settings are necessary for Intellij to correctly start it.

dependencies must contain: implementation enforcedPlatform(libs.quarkusPlatform)
plugins must contain: id 'io.quarkus'





So to conclude:

The Modules currently need to be Quarkus-Modules (having the quarkus-plugin and the quarkus-bom), because otherwise the Tests would not run in Intellij
The Modules use Quarkus-Arc, and Quarkus-Arc needs to be provided with Inject-Targets during! the Build, otherwise it will complain / abort the build.


For the Unit-Tests (or unit-tests run during build) i can just write a TestProfile-Class that replaces the application.properties file and seems to be good.
For the Build itself, i can not do this, as the TestProfile Class is only intended for Unit-Tests. Therefore i must use application.properties file providing the defaults.

Finally now to my question:

Is there something i have missed in the Quarkus Arc documentation in regards to such a Multi-Module Setup?
Can someone point me to how i could refactor my project to make the Modules more independent and self-contained.
Do i need to put an application.properties file in my modules also, so i can build them with Quarkus Arc in mind? While this seems to work, it seems wrong, because then i need to provide wrong/placeholder properties just to satisfy the Arc Build.


Are you using Quarkus build on all of those modules? What I do is I build only 1 module with Quarkus, the one that will be deployed. All others are plain jars with the appropriate dependencies.

I need to use Quarkus build in those modules, because i also catch startup events or define database (datasource) in the modules which does need quarkus arc for setting them up. My modules also contain Beans that need to be discovered by Arc (via beans.xml). I also have Unit-Tests in those modules with QuarkusTest which also needs to be executed during the build (in ci). For example, i define a StartupEvent in my Core Module, that sets common settings for all Services that depend on it.

you can have a look at the multi-module project here, if it helps: https://github.com/funkrusher/fk-framework-quarkus-jooq

i know that i have a very specific setup, which makes it hart to answer my question. I tried to add some more details into the question.

I experiment with various tricks to get around the problems you describe. Some of them are: use weld-junit5 to run tests (not a 1-1 replacement of ArC, but will do most of the times); use Quarkus-specific functionality (like @Startup) only from the Quarkus module, but the other modules provide CDI beans with the functionality (e.g. a @Startup bean in the Quarkus module invokes a method of a CDI bean in another module that contains the real functionality - so you can consider the startup bean as an adaptor of the functionality to Quarkus);

when I need to configure a bean in a non-Quarkus module I define a configuration interface and implement it in the Quarkus module (perhaps with the microprofile config); similar for when I need other resources created in a Quarkus-specific way. I know this is not an answer to your problem, just my take! Good luck!

thank you, that sounds like a good way to go. I will try to factor out quarkus-code vs. non-quarkus code like you said. Still a bit of a bummer, because the QuarkusTest made some things easier to setup because it already has concepts for Test-Execution, but i guess Junit5 will also do the trick.

also interesting,
the "AgroalDataSource" is not even a "Bean" in the sense of a Quarkus Bean for CDI. It has no bean annotation. I need to read the quarkus docs a bit more, because i wonder why i can even inject it, as i thought only Beans (@RequestContext, @ApplicationContext, ...) can be Injected with Quarkus Arc. But thats another topic :)

I had luck with adding Quarkus dependencies in test scope and running them as @QuarkusTests. E.g. RESTEasy reactive, for which the implementation is actually Quarkus. Just some more info - Good luck again!
